# Vue - Filter 2D Array but modify original unfiltered array v-models

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter

I have an array of objects and each object has 7 keys, each key contains an object.
GB,GI,DE are the keys of the object
Example:

```
foo[0] contains {
GB:  { example: "example" , example1: "example1"},
FI:  { example: "example" , example1: "example1"},
DE:  { example: "example" , example1: "example1"},
ETC,ETC
}
```

I am outputting this 2D array with a v-for and inside the v-for, I have select options and text fields, etc to manipulate the data in the array. Therefore each select option or text field has a v-model assigned to the index of the current element in order to be able to manipulate the data of the array.

Now I would like to add a search bar to search for a particular element. This can be done by adding a filter and looping through the items in this filtered array. However, if I do this I won't be able to manipulate the data in the original Array as the new filtered array will have different indexes

How can I go around this, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using the objects name/id as reference for the original array?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, objects are a reference type so you can use its reference in a new array and then mutate it.

```html
<div id='app'>
  <input v-model='search'>
  <div v-for='item in filteredItems'>
    <label>{{ item.name }}</label>
    <input v-model='item.input'>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    search: '',
    items: [
      {
        name: 'maculomancy',
        input: 'divination using spots'
      },
      {
        name: 'forficulate',
        input: 'like scissors'
      },
      {
        name: 'wainage',
        input: 'cultivation of land'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter(item =>
        new RegExp(this.search, 'i').test(item.name)
      )
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8bdrtqyp/)